# Code-First CTP5 navigational properties generates wrong column names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have the following model and configuration:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.HasOptional(u => u.CreatedBy);
        this.Property(u => u.DateCreated);

        this.Property(u => u.Name).HasMaxLength(64);
        this.Property(u => u.Username).HasMaxLength(64);
    }
}

public class SampleContext : DbContext
{

    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public SampleContext(string dbConnection)
        : base(dbConnection)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

I can work with the context and add users just fine. I then was looking at the table generated by Code First and realized that the `CreatedBy` property isn't generating a `CreatedById` column but rather a `UserId` column. If I add another property such as `ModifiedBy` it will generate `UserId1` and so on:

[image]

I tried mapping with `HasRequired()` as well but the property still generates a column name that matches the actual type and *not* the property name. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to create a Self-Reference Independent Association with a custom Foreign Key column name and here is the fluent API code to do this:

```
public UserConfiguration()
{
    this.HasRequired(u => u.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .IsIndependent()
        .Map(m => 
        {
            m.MapKey(u => u.Id, "CreatedById");
        });
}
```

However, this code throws an exception due to a bug in CTP5. Hence, for the time being, you can use the suggested workaround in MSDN forum (changing your independent association to FK association and explicitly name your FK property) and save this code for the RTM next year.

Comment: +1 Awesome to know! I still think that this should be the *default* naming convention. There just seems to be some issues like no *true* enum support, not allowing configurations by inheritance (see one of my posts on MSDN) etc. I will save this for RTM though! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem :) BTW, I couldn't find your thread about "configurations by inheritance" can you please provide me with the link?

Comment: Here's the thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/ebe48aa3-14df-475e-bc5e-80734f85ace4

Comment: Thanks for the link. BTW, I've started a series on Inheritance Mapping & EF Code First CTP5 which you might find useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I cross [posted this on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/a025c90d-159c-4e73-a887-f14fb9bb1813/) and I guess that this is, so far, by design. All navigational properties generate the *type name* + Id for the column name. To me this is a fundamental design flaw in code-first. The names generated don't even reflect the column (except that it's a User).

Answer (score 0):

You can overrule the default column names using HasColumnName(...)

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
         this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

         this.HasOptional(u => u.CreatedBy);
         // Map the 'DateCreated' Property to the 'CreatedById' table field.
         this.Property(u => u.DateCreated).HasColumnName("CreatedById");

         this.Property(u => u.Name).HasMaxLength(64);
         this.Property(u => u.Username).HasMaxLength(64);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why would I map `DateCreated` to the *Id* of `CreatedBy`? That doesn't make any sense. `HasColumnName` is only available on non-navigational properties.

Comment: Sorry about that. My mistake. Misread your question completely.

Comment: No worries :). I was hoping to have the `HasColumnName` as well but if you take a look at the MSDN like in my post, you'll see that it's not even possible to control the navigational property names.